# oAuth1 initiation - 404

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to get oauth access token for a third party application, following documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html).
However, I always end up with a 404 error. I tried with different clients (python and postman), with different signature methods (`HMAC` and `PLAINTEXT`). I also tried to put the `oauth_callback` as a request param (against offical doc, but I saw that in another tutorial) but it didn't help either. I'm attaching a screenshot displaying the python script used and the output showing the correctly constructed `Authorization` header (I'm not sure if I should put the `/index.php` in the `BASE_URL` so I tried both). Also, I (obviously) anonymized the key and secret after execution.

[image]

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was: the API url must contain the country code, so for example: https://domain.com/en/oauth/initiate